# Transfer of variables across pages

Tags: php

I have a form that allows users to enter the info such as "Title", "Description".

INDEX.PHP

```
    <form action="action.php" method="POST">
     <p>Video Title</p>   <input type="text" name="title"> <br>
     <p>Video Link</p> <input type="text" name="Link"> <br>
     <p>Description</p> <input type="text" name="desc"> <br>
     <p>Page Name</p>   <input type="text" name="pagename"> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

But I send that form info to action.php where it duplicates video.php (VideoPlayer page)

ACTION.PHP

```
<?php


$title = htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']);
$link = htmlspecialchars($_POST['link']);
$desc = htmlspecialchars($_POST['desc']);
$pgname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['pagename']);


copy('video.php', $pgname . '.html');

$myFile = $pgname . '.html';

$ch = curl_init($myFile);
$output = curl_exec($ch);

?>
```

VIDEO.PHP

```
   ` <title><?php  echo $_POST["$title"]; ?></title>`
   <?php 

  echo '<source src="'.$link.'" type="video/mp4">' ?>
```

How can I get the variables from action.php like $title and $pgname into video.php.

The page has to be duplicated so I can have an original to work off of.

Comment: if thats a simple string, just use query strings, `video.php?title=whatevertitle` sidenote: be careful with directory traversal though

Comment: Why do you use this weird code? You can not output html directly in action.php?

Comment: @RodrigoDuterte Wouldn't that require a database though?

Comment: @fusion3k Would that be storing the html in a variable in action.php?

Comment: @KryometricGaming require a database? that just utilizes `$_GET` variables

Comment: You can directly echo it. Or you can use `include( 'video.php' )`: using `include()`, all your variables are directly available to included file.

Comment: @fusion3k So I could echo the variable across the two pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your code with variables from action.php scope, follow markt answer.
If you want to redirect from action.php to video.php page, follow Pedro Lobito answer.

Please note that you can obtain same result of your actual code using this code in action.php:

```
(...)
$desc = htmlspecialchars( $_POST['desc'] );
include( 'video.php' );
```

But probably you don't want that. As per your comment:

> I want to make it permanent, so it can be archived...

Neither your code or answers will make your specific video page permanent: they simply copy existent php code on new files, without storing any information about specific video.

To do that, you have to use a different method. Something like this (action.php):

```
$title  = htmlspecialchars( $_POST['title'] );
$link   = htmlspecialchars( $_POST['link'] );
$desc   = htmlspecialchars( $_POST['desc'] );
$pgname = htmlspecialchars( $_POST['pagename'] );

$html = <<<EOT
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>$title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>$desc</p>
    <source src="$link" type="video/mp4">
</body>
</html>
EOT;

$myFile = $pgname . '.html';

if( ! file_put_contents( $myFile, $html ) )
{
    die( "Error saving $myFile" );
}
else
{
    header( 'Location: $myFile' );
    exit;
}
```

In short, you set a variable (above I use [Heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax) with appropriate video data (title, link, description), then you save it in a new file and redirect user to new file location.

Comment: I'll try this, but I did try this `<title><?php  echo $_POST["pagename"]; ?></title>` and have the form directly go to video.php. But the only problem is that it didn't duplicate.

Comment: Yes, I know. This answer create instead a new file for each video. Please note that on some server you have to add a delay before `header` call. If you see a '404 not found' add `usleep(400000);` before `header` line.

Comment: It worked great, your code used the the html in the php file to make an entire new page. Beautiful, and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the variables from action.php like $title and $pgname
>   into video.php.

To pass variables from one `php` script to another use [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php), i.e.:

**action.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['title'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']); //some title
```

**video.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['title'];
//some title
```

Comment: OP load video.php through curl.

Comment: The file is on the same server, there's absolutely no reason to use curl. He's just trying to pass variables to another script.

Comment: I agree that is a weird method (see my previous comment), but OP code do that.

Comment: I'm on SO for +15H and I'm getting tired... :)

Comment: I want to make it permanent, so it can be archived and what not

Answer (score 1):

You need to post your variables in your curl function.

Convert your vars into a query string:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) { 
    $post_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
}
rtrim($post_string, '&');
```

Then add to your curl setup:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($_POST));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
```

And your copy of video.php - must be a php file!

```
copy('video.php', $pgname . '.php');

$myFile = $pgname . '.php';
```

For a full example see
https://davidwalsh.name/curl-post